# How to handle $key when using ngrx?

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, ngrx

When using AngularFire2 and ngrx, I noticed that $key isn't persisted to the store with my objects.

Reviewing the source, you can see that AngularFire2 sets $key as `enumerable:false` which I'm assuming prevents it from serializing with the object.

What's the best way to handle $key?

Ideally I could have it serialize with the object to the store.

Comment: You'd need to use a `map` operator. Unfortunately, that means instances will always be mapped and will always be different and that does not play nice with Angular's `OnPush` change detection. It's one of the reasons that I abandoned AngularFire2. See [this PR](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/888) and its associated issues for more information.

Comment: thanks @cartant. I actually did see your PR which sent me on the hunt. I commented regarding it in the Google group. I'd hate to abandon the official lib though. Any idea why they didn't accept or discuss your PR?

Comment: I have some idea, but this really isn't the forum for discussing it. The PR's [branch in my fork](https://github.com/cartant/angularfire2/commits/issue-883) is still there if it's of any use to you. I just grew too impatient with AF2 and no longer wanted it as a dependency.